# AuthenticationFailed: MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document on sharded MongoDB: Failed to connect to: queryrouter0.example.com:27017:

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, authentication

I have a sharded MongoDB setup.

I'm trying to connect to it from my Laravel application

Before I sharded my database I was using [laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) to connect to my regular mongodb instance.

This was my previous config

```
'mongodb' => array(
        'driver'   => 'mongodb',
        'host'     => env('MONGODB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port'     => env('MONGODB_PORT', 27017),
        'username' => env('MONGODB_USERNAME', ''),
        'password' => env('MONGODB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'database' => env('MONGODB_DATABASE', ''),
        'options' => array(
            'db' => env('MONGODB_AUTHDATABASE', '') //Sets the auth DB
        )
    )
```

I tried to update the `MONGODB_HOST` to the sharded query router hostname but I am now getting the error

> [MongoConnectionException]
>     Failed to connect to: queryrouter0.example.com:27017: Authentication failed on database 'admin' with username 'maxrosecollins': auth failed`

I can see in the logs on the `queryrouter0.example.com` server

> 2017-09-05T14:42:36.558+0000 I NETWORK  [thread2] connection accepted from 45.32.144.169:33086 #41615 (1 connection now open)
>   2017-09-05T14:42:36.560+0000 I ACCESS   [conn41615]  authenticate db: admin { authenticate: 1, user: "maxrosecollins", nonce: "xxx", key: "xxx" }
>
> 2017-09-05T14:42:36.562+0000 I ACCESS   [conn41615] Failed to authenticate maxrosecollins@admin with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed: MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
>
> 2017-09-05T14:42:36.563+0000 I -        [conn41615] end connection 45.32.144.169:33086 (1 connection now open)

I can connect to the query router using the following.
This is on the same server I am getting the auth failed error when using laravel. I have double checked passwords and usernames

```
mongo queryrouter0.example.com:27017 -u "maxrosecollins" -p "password" --authenticationDatabase "admin"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out my `laravel-mongodb` install was version 2 which doesn't support the `SCRAM-SHA-1` authentication mechanism.

I used `composer update`to upgrade to version 3 which also meant upgrading the php mongo adapter along with a lot of other dependencies.

I then ran `db.adminCommand({authSchemaUpgrade: 1});` [see upgrading auth](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-scram/)

After this I could authenticate with my mongo query router

Answer (score 0):

```
'connections' => [
     'mongodb' => [
      'driver'   => 'mongodb',
      'dsn' => 'mongodb://User:password@xxx-shard-00-00-uggj0.mongodb.net:27017,xxx-shard-00-01-uggj0.mongodb.net:27017,xxx-shard-00-02-uggj0.mongodb.net:27017/homestead?ssl=true&replicaSet=xxx-shard-0&authSource=admin',
      'database' => 'homestead',

  ],
```

i can connect like this to my cloud atlas

Comment: Shouldn't  I be connecting to the query router not the shards?